# Capistrano deployment failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Got the following error while trying to `cap deploy:setup`. It's like it failed to upload the database.yml file via sftp. I googled everywhere but had no solution. Not even a bit.

> *** upload via sftp failed on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Net::SFTP::StatusException (Net::SFTP::StatusException open /var/www/domain.com/username/shared/config/database.yml (3, "permission denied"))
>   upload via sftp failed on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Net::SFTP::StatusException (Net::SFTP::StatusException open /var/www/domain.com/username/shared/config/database.yml (3, "permission denied"))

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two reasons for this:

- the directory tree was not created (less likely as it would be error before)
- you do not have rights to the following path on server:

  - check if the path exists ( if not create it: md path)
  - check if you can cd to it as the deploy user ( if not grab rights to it: chown -R deploy_user: /path)